# Regex for monomials

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a string is a monomial, ie either a:

- constant (may be a positive or negative decimal)
- variable (any letter)
- exponential value w/ or w/out a constant (ce^x)
- variable w/ exponent (x^n)
- constant w/ variable (cn)
- or constant w/ variable and exponent

However the only one that seems to work is if its a constant (and an integer, decimals would fail).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is what I have:

```
if(!userAnswer.matches("-?\\d*\\.?\\d*e\\^-?\\d*\\.?\\d*x") && //exponential
        !userAnswer.matches("-?\\d*\\.?") && //constant
        !userAnswer.matches("-?\\[a-zA-Z]") && //variable
        !userAnswer.matches("-?\\d*\\.?\\[a-zA-Z]") && //constant w/ variable
        !userAnswer.matches("-?\\[a-zA-Z]\\^-?\\d*\\.") && //variable w/ exponent
        !userAnswer.matches("-?\\d*\\.?\\[a-zA-Z]\\^-?\\d*\\."))//constant w/ variable w/ exponent
{//do something}
```

Examples that should work, but do not work:
"3x", "-x", 3y^4", "6.12e^2.0x", "d^-90"

Comment: It looks like your pattern for constants allows a decimal point, but no digits following it.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, your pattern for constants appears to accept several strings it probably shouldn't, the empty string not least among them.

Comment: Is it intentional that your "variable with exponent" patterns allow a trailing decimal point in the exponent (but no fractional digits), but your exponential pattern allows both a decimal point and fractional digits in the exponent?

Comment: Your pattern seems to assume that the variable in the exponential form will be specifically `x`.  Is that all you are supposed to allow?

Comment: Your pattern for the exponential form appears intended to allow *two* constants, one as a coefficient and one in the exponent.  Your prose description only mentions one.  Which is right?

Comment: It would be appropriate to present some of the actual strings you want to match successfully, but that your code fails to match, and / or some of the strings that your code does match, but shouldn't.

Comment: No I saw an example for decimals that used that and assumed it was correct. For the constant, I check the string before hand if its empty or not, but what other issues does it have?

Comment: The exponential one is unintentional, I did not notice that it would accept fractions, and I honestly still dont see it.

Comment: The exponential form may accept one with or without a constant in front, but must contain an exponent

Comment: I have provided some examples that should work but do not work. The only case where is currently works is if I only enter an integer.

Comment: In which category `6.12e^2.0x` should fit on? It's not clear

Comment: @ Cristik for exponential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at all your regular expressions and see what can be done (I have replaced all the `\\` escapes to `\` for clarity.

```
"-?\d*\.?\d*e\^-?\d*\.?\d*x" - exponential
"-?\d*\.?" - constant
"-?\[a-zA-Z]" - variable
"-?\d*\.?\[a-zA-Z]" - constant w/ variable
"-?\[a-zA-Z]\^-?\d*\." - variable w/ exponent
"-?\d*\.?\[a-zA-Z]\^-?\d*\." - constant w/ variable w/ exponent
```

In the exponential expression, you are allowing a `\d` of length zero to infinity. That means that this statement matches: `e^x`

The expression can also match `2.e^6x`, which is clearly invalid as there is a decimal with no numbers after it.

We can fix this by doing the following:

> -?\d+(?:.\d+)?e\^-?\d+(?:.\d+)?x

By swapping the `*` for a `+`, we tell it to match one or more of the selected. This means there must be at least one number. By grouping the decimal and the following `\d`, we tell it if there is a decimal, it must be followed by at least one more number.

The expression for the constant value suffers from the same zero-length number flaw. Furthermore, it doesn't match any numbers after the decimal point.

> -?\d+(?:.\d+)?

The expression for a variable has escaped the `[` character, meaning that it will only match the following two strings: `-[a-zA-Z]` and `[a-zA-Z]`. I am assuming this is not intentional. To fix this, we simply remove the backslash.

> -?[a-zA-Z]

The expression for a constant with a variable has the same mistakes as the expressions above (zero numbers, no numbers after the decimal point, escaped `[`)

> -?\d+(?:.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]

The expression for a variable with an exponent also has the same mistakes

> -?[a-zA-Z]\^-?\d+(?:.\d+)?

Finally, the expression for a constant with a variable and exponent:

> -?\d+(?:.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]\^-?\d+(?:.\d+)?

Comment: To the person who downvoted, mind telling me what's wrong?

Comment: Not my downvote, but this does not appear to be a very complete answer to the question.  It has no detail and offers no solution.

Comment: Very well. I will edit my answer to be more precise. I wasn't sure how much detail I should add as too much makes it seem like spoonfeeding

Comment: What you actually wrote would have been more appropriate for a comment on the question.  And perhaps that's all this question warrants.

Comment: Do you intentionally allow your constants to begin with an insignificant `0` digit (e.g. "01")?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Misplaced comment?

Comment: oops, yes, misplaced comment.

Comment: Thanks you! I was looking into some of the documentation and realized that I totally forgot to fix the case if its something like 3.x, rather than 3.0x

Comment: One more thing, what does the : 'colon' mean?

Comment: I assume you mean the `(?:stuff here)`. The `?:` means that this group will not be a capturing group, so if you add new capture groups it won't interfere